# Where can I find the Analyze Data button in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-addins

I was trying to pull out some sample data in excel from the Home button, and then Analyze Data.

I have tried add-ins, but it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

Which Excel version are you using (..., 2019, 2021, 365) and in which language?

From the Microsoft site:

> Analyze Data is available to Microsoft 365 subscribers in English,
> French, Spanish, German, Simplified Chinese, and Japanese. If you are
> a Microsoft 365 subscriber, make sure you have the latest version of
> Office. To learn more about the different update channels for Office,
> see: Overview of update channels for Microsoft 365 apps. [Link to
> Microsoft Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/analyze-data-in-excel-3223aab8-f543-4fda-85ed-76bb0295ffc4)